# Why @@rowcount returns 0 when more than 1 user access store procedure for insertion

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

i am using asp.net, i am calling insertion store procedure whihc works fine until one person is inserting but throw error when more than 1 person simultaneously inserts records i.e. @@RowCount stores 0 and returns 0 to application.

USE [CPOCMS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[InsertComplaints]    Script Date: 9/24/2014 11:56:13 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertComplaints]
    @ComplaintCode varchar(50),
    @ComplaintType_ID smallint,
    @RecievingMode_ID smallint,
    @Subject varchar(100),
    @ComplainantID smallint,
    @District_ID smallint,
    @AddressedTo varchar(50),
    @DiaryNo varchar(50),
    @User_ID int,
    @Status_ID smallint,
    @RecievedDate smalldatetime,
    @IGRemarks varchar(MAX) = null,
    @PsoRemarks varchar(MAX) =null,
    @FinalDecision varchar(250)=null,
    @AgainstDist_ID smallint,
    @HomePS_ID smallint,
    @AgainstPS_ID smallint, 
    @Name varchar(75),
    @DesigID int,
    @ForwardedBy smallint,
    @SMS_ID int = 0,
    @result bit output,
    @ID int output

AS
BEGIN
   Begin Try

        insert into dbo.Complaints
        values (
        @ComplaintCode,
        @ComplaintType_ID,
        @RecievingMode_ID ,
        @Subject,
        @ComplainantID ,
        @District_ID ,
        @AddressedTo ,
        @DiaryNo,
        @User_ID,
        @Status_ID,
        @RecievedDate,
        @IGRemarks,
        @PsoRemarks,
        @FinalDecision,
        @AgainstDist_ID,
        @HomePS_ID,
        @AgainstPS_ID,
        @Name ,
        @DesigID,
        @ForwardedBy,
        @SMS_ID
        ) 

        Set @result = @@ROWCOUNT 

        Select @ID= Ident_Current('dbo.Complaints')

   End Try

   Begin Catch
        Set @result=0
   End Catch

END
```

in sql it shows @@Rowcount = 0 and in asp.net it returns @result=0 , why ?

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Boolean Result = Convert.ToBoolean(pResult.Value);
            if (Result)
            {
                int i = Convert.ToInt32(pID.Value);
                return i;
            }            
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
```

Note: i have removed unnecessary code.

Comment: In `catch` you are suppressing all errors and returning `0`- may that's why you see `0` in your front end?

Comment: Are you sure you are not violating some constraint when a second users inserts?

Comment: There's no way that @@Rowcount would return 0 if any rows were affected. You're failing in the insert and going to the Catch block directly.